# Adjustment created at type = Invoice level

Tags: oracle, oracle-apps

User adjusted some amount over an invoice at **type = INVOICE** level where adjusted anount is less  than tha invoice amount 
He must receive an error : 
**APP-AR-11503: Invoice type adjustment must make the balance due zero**. 
but user manages to save that invoice I am not able to replicate that issue is my test instance please suggest and advise.

Comment: This isn't *pure* Oracle (PL/)SQL, is it? Perhaps EBS or something like that? If so, please, edit tags and pick the appropriate one(s).

Comment: Actually I tries to tag oracle R12 or AR but did find any related tags. This issue is related to Oracle Apps r12 Account Receivables.

Comment: OK, I tagged it. Unfortunately, I know nothing about it so I can't assist. I hope someone else will be able to help.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem, John.